# concurrency in user-level and kernel-level threads. why are the outputs different?

Tags: c, multithreading

I am getting started learning about threads, and now I get to the point when the book confuses me with user-level and kernel-level threads.

The book puts much emphasis on the differences and presents a problem, saying the outputs for the following two similar codes are different, however, (to my knowledge), the outputs of them appear to be the same to me.

The first one is about user-level thread:

```
int number = 0;
int main() {
fork()
if it is child {number--, return 0}
if it is parent {number++, wait till child return, print number}}
```

my analysis is that since number-- and number++ have to be executed only once, and the output will be printed out after these two executions, so the output must be 0.

The second case is about kernel-level thread:

```
int number = 0;
t1() {number--}
t2() {number++}
main() {
    createThread(pass t1)
    createThread(pass t2)
    wait till both complete
    print number
}
```

In this case, same thing, the kernel creates two threads, one --, another ++, so both of them have to be executed only once. and the result must be 0 again.

However, the book says the outputs are different, or there might be different outputs because of intervening, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Which book says that `fork()` is used to implement user-level threads so I can tell our library to ban it?

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, its not creating threads, but instead forking a process (look up the description of the fork() function). A forked process has its own memory, copied from the parent process, so the result of decrementing the number in the child process will have no affect in the parent process. The result of printing number in the parent process will be 1.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you wrote a single instruction `i++` or `i--` it may be translated to more than one instruction in machine language. If you are using Kernel threads, these two computations may run on different cores, each caching "their" value of `i`. The result actually written to memory in this case is undefined, because the hardware and the compiler assume no one is modifying data behind their back.

Answer (score 0):

In the threaded case it is possible to obtain `1` or even `-1` as the final value because of possible data race. Since there is no guarantee that thread 2 will be started after thread 1 has finished or vice versa, without proper synchronisation it is possible that both threads start at around the same time and see the initial value of `0`. Then depending on which thread finishes second, the value would be either `1` or `-1` instead of `0`. To avoid this, sychronisation idioms like critical sections or atomic in-/decrements have to be used.